# use provided gateway 2001:4ba0:fffd:1:beef::1 /128 instead of fe80::1.

Tags: freebsd, ipv6

I am trying to setup some IPV6 address on a [FreeBSD 11](https://www.freebsd.org/) server, I was told to use as a gateway this IP:

```
2001:4ba0:fffd:1:beef::1 /128
```

My addresses are:

```
2001:4ba0:fffd:0063::0 /64
```

I tried this:

```
ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="YES"
ipv6_defaultrouter="2001:4ba0:fffd:1:beef::1"
ifconfig_bge0_ipv6="inet6 2001:4ba0:fffd:0063::1 prefixlen 64"
```

But I get this message:

```
route: writing to routing socket: Network is unreachable
add net default: gateway 2001:4ba0:fffd:1:beef::1 fib 0: Network is unreachable
```

By doing an `npd -a` I got this:

```
> ndp -a
Neighbor                             Linklayer Address  Netif Expire    S Flags
2001:4ba0:fffd:63::1                 2c:44:fd:9a:3f:90   bge0 permanent R
fe80::1%bge0                         28:92:4a:cd:08:18   bge0 22h8m42s  S R
fe80::2a92:4aff:fecd:818%bge0        28:92:4a:cd:08:18   bge0 23h27m31s S R
fe80::2e44:fdff:fe9a:3f90%bge0       2c:44:fd:9a:3f:90   bge0 permanent R
```

Then I give a try to use as a default router `fe80::1.`:

```
ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="YES"
ipv6_defaultrouter="fe80::1%bge0"
ifconfig_bge0_ipv6="inet6 2001:4ba0:fffd:0063::1 prefixlen 64"
```

When using the [link-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) `fe80::1` address as the gateway, IPV6  works.

I would like to know what are the advantages/disadvantagtes of using the link-local address as the gateway and also how to use the provied gateway or using either is the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPv6 gateway address your got (`2001:4ba0:fffd:1:beef::1`) is not inside the subnet you got (`2001:4ba0:fffd:0063::/64`) so your box is right to complain that that network is unreachable.

Using the link-local address as default gateway is usually a good solution, as long as the link-local address of the gateway doesn't change. The address `fe80::1` looks like a manually configured address which would indicate that it is provided intentionally and therefore probably stable.

It doesn't really matter what address you use for a gateway. The only thing that the address is used for is to determine the layer-2 (MAC) address of the gateway so that packets can be sent there. Whether the MAC address is found by looking up a global address or by using a link-local address doesn't make any difference for the actual packets being routed.